Conditional Expectancy Problem of Independent Geometric Distributed Variables
let $i = {1,2,...,6}$ each person $i$ throws the die until he gets the result $i$ and $X_i$ is equal to the amount the die was thrown.
calculate $E[\sum_{i = 1}^6 X_i |X_1 + X_2 = 10]$
what I did was:
$E[\sum_{i = 1}^6 X_i |X_1 + X_2 = 10] = E[\sum_{i=3}^6 (X_i) + 10] = E[\sum_{i=3}^6 X_i] + 10$
because $X_i$ are independent $E[\sum_{i=3}^6 X_i] + 10 = \sum_{i=3}^6 (E[X_i]) + 10 = 18 + 10 = 28$
I'm not quite sure if it's correct or not because I did what felt right but I couldn't find a common example and when I used formulas such as $E[X|Y = y] = \sum_x (x \frac{P(X = x, Y = y)}{P(Y = y)})$
I wasn't able to solve it.

Your approach is fine (except for miscounting), but probably you should show & justify each step:
$$\begin{align}
&E[\sum_{i = 1}^6 X_i |X_1 + X_2 = 10]\\
=&E[X_1+X_2 |X_1 + X_2 = 10] + E[\sum_{i = 3}^6 X_i |X_1 + X_2 = 10]\quad\text{by linearity of expectation}\\
=& 10 + E[\sum_{i = 3}^6 X_i]\quad\text{because $(X_1,X_2)$ and   $(X_3,X_4,X_5,X_6)$ are indep.}\\
=& 10 + \sum_{i = 3}^6E[X_i]\quad\text{by linearity of expectation}\\
=& 10 + \sum_{i = 3}^6{6}\quad\text{by expectation of each Geom(1/6) r.v.}\\
=& 10 + 4\cdot 6\\
=& 34
\end{align}$$
